# sqlserver group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need some guidance writing an optimal query. I have a table that looks like this:

```
CompanyID   EmployerAddress        DateVerified
1           12 Main St, Devon PA
2           32 Church St, Concord MA
3           12 Main St, Devon PA
4           999 Elm St, Salem MA
5           999 Elm St, Salem MA
```

I have to verify this Employer Address using geocoding in C# program(I have the written that & works for single records). If the address is OK then I update Dateverified to today's date. I have about 10000 records. Since CompanyID 1 and 3;  4 & 5 have same address, I do not want to verify for each one. How can I group it by addresses and update their date? I used

```
select 
    EMployeraddress,
    CompanyID 
from 
    Companies 
group by 
    EMployeraddress,
    CompanyID 
having 
    count(EMployerAddress) > 1;
```

But this is not giving me the right result. Can anyone help me.

Thanks
Rashmi

Comment: Please exapnd on "not giving me the right result"

Comment: When I do Update Companies set Dateverified=getdate() Select 
    EMployeraddress,
    CompanyID 
from 
    Companies 
group by 
    EMployeraddress,
    CompanyID 
having 
    count(EMployerAddress) > 1; It is updating all the rows. If I have verified Row 1, I want the query to look for other records that match address i.e. Row 3 and update it's date too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the id for that.

1) select address

```
select 
    EMployeraddress
from 
    Companies 
group by 
    EMployeraddress
```

2) check it with your code

3) update the table

```
UPDATE your_table
SET DateVerified = (SELECT now())
WHERE EmployerAddress = 'your_address'
```

Comment: 1. So, In my call to geocoding, 
Select distinct EmployeeAddress from Companies;
--for each row call geocoding and then call the below update
update Companies set dateverified=getdate()
  (SELECT distinct 
    EmployeeAddress
from 
    Companies where keyid=@keyid
);

Is this Correct??

Comment: You can do it for one operation. Then you don't need *keyid*. Just update all table at once where the addresses are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the address is just a string representing the address, then if it's not consistent you're not going to have consistent results.

Usually you'd store addresses in a separate table, and you'd have a foreign key in the Companies table pointing to the Addresses table. This way you could really group by foreign key.

If all you have is a string, then as I said, if they are not consistenly entered, there's not much you can do.

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, its a string. I am curious, if i create a Address table, wouldn't u need addressID as another column

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by foreign key pointing to the Address table :-)

Answer (score 0):

Am I right or not ? But I think that all you need is :

```
UPDATE Companies SET DateVerified = GETDATE() 
WHERE EmployerAddress = 'TheVerified Address'
```